# How to pass Byte value to JPQL in Spring?

Tags: spring, jpa, integer, byte

I have an Interface which extends `JpaRepository<ArticlesEntity, Integer>`

I have method in it:

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM ArticlesEntity a " +
        "WHERE ((:approved = 2 ) or (a.approved = :approved)) ")
Page<ArticlesEntity> filterByAllPage(
        @Param("approved") Byte approved,
        Pageable pageable);
```

When this method is invoked I have an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]

When I change

```
(:approved = 2 )
```

to

```
 (:approved is null)
```

or

```
@Param("approved") Byte approved
```

to

```
@Param("approved") Integer approved
```

or

```
"WHERE ((:approved = 2 ) or (a.approved = :approved))"
```

to

```
"WHERE (a.approved = :approved) "
```

it works.

It seems that should be something like

```
 (:approved = (byte) 2 )
```

or

```
(:approved=2.byteValue())
```

but both didn't work also.

Is there any way to use Byte here or it's better to switch to Integer?

The database is MySQL and it has table "articles" with column "approved" of "TINYINT(1)" type.

Comment: what is underlying database? AFAIK Postrgres wants to have strict type, other are more tolerant

Comment: The underneath table column is defined as TINYINT?

Comment: yes, TINYINT(1)